# pyodbc connection timeout no triggered when run with WHILE loop

Tags: python, sql-server, timeout, pyodbc

I wrote this code expecting it to throw a timeout exception:

```
import pyodbc

constr = 'MY CONNECTION STRING...'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(constr)
cnxn.autocommit = True
cnxn.timeout = 2
query = """WHILE 1 = 1
                BEGIN
                DECLARE @var INT 
                END"""
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute(query)
```

However if I change the query to

```
query = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:04'"
```

the timeout exception is raised,

anyone know why?

note - using SQL Server 2016

Comment: When you changed to WAITFOR did you also add a pyodbc fetch call?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - nope everything else is the same